# Create model that inherits from DBContext from SQL's view

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is it possible to create a model, inherit from `DBContext` which points to existing view in SQL?

How would be the syntax?

Comment: Yes. Or any other way that will give me the possiblty to inherit from DBContext w/o declaring again connection with SQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Linq To Sql wich is no longer supported.
It's more fun and pertinent to choose Entity Framework (code first, model first or database first).

- Add a new entity data model to your project 
  [image: add new model]
- Define connection string
- Add the view to the model

[image: select view]

- Query your view

  using (var dbcontext = new MyEntities())
          {
              //var res = dbcontext.MyView.Where(...).ToList();
          }